# Cumulative sums vector in R

Tags: r

i have an assignment for studies and i need to create a function that takes a vector as input and creates another vector, which, at every position has a cumulative sum of the previous ones and itself, it might be unclear but i have some code, and have no idea whats wrong. I cant use cumsum()

```
SumaKumul <- function(x)
{
  result <- c()
  for(i in x)
  {
    result[i] <- sum(x[1:i])
  }
  return(result)
}

SumaKumul(c(2,3,4,5))
```

and thats what i get

```
> SumaKumul(c(2,3,4,5))
[1] NA  5  9 14 NA
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `seq_along(x)`, rather than `x` in your `for` loop

```
SumaKumul <- function(x)
{
  result <- c()
  for(i in seq_along(x))
  {
    result[i] <- sum(x[1:i])
  }
  return(result)
}
```

such that

```
> SumaKumul(c(2,3,4,5))
[1]  2  5  9 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `1:length(x)` in your `for` loop of a function to iterate over a vector:

```
SumaKumul <- function(x)
    {
      result <- c()
      for(i in 1:length(x))
      {
        result[i] <- sum(x[1:i])
      }
      return(result)
    }

SumaKumul(c(2,3,4,5))
# [1]  2  5  9 14
```

Comment: @MarcinKoc Please consider accepting answer if it worked for you.